# Slide between premade/separate pages using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some separately made HTML pages that id like to slide horizontally between.

Ive looked everywhere but I havent found exactly what Im looking for. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you talking about loading the pages via AJAX ?

Comment: I'm trying to use the PageSlide jQuery plugin but it doesnt work exactly as i want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a plugin written for a fully general solution for completely different pages. It would need some kind of an AJAX load, and a nice transition with possible history manipulation.

I don't know how well it suits your needs, but the old [Google HTML5 slide template](https://code.google.com/p/html5slides/) had this functionality.

There are limitations on what you can do with it, but they provide convenient keyboard and mouse navigation.